# Create Simple Controller Not Working In My Module in Magento 1.9.2?

Tags: magento-1.9, module, controllers

I am Trying To create a Simple Module. It's Found 404 page Error.

My config file in ***app/etc/modules/Codefire_Mymodule.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Codefire_Mymodule>
            <actve>true</actve>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Codefire_Mymodule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Create Controllrer in *app\code\local\Codefire\Mymodule\controllers\IndexController.php*

```
<?php
class Codefire_Mymodule_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo "Hello tuts+ World";
    }
     public function testAction()
    {
        echo "test action";
    }
}
```

And Create My Plugin xml file in ***app\code\local\Codefire\Mymodule\etc\config.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Codefire_Mymodule>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Codefire_Mymodule>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <mymodule>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Codefire_Mymodule</module>
                    <frontName>mymodule</frontName>
                </args>
            </mymodule>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

URL: index.php/mymodule/index/index
When I am Write testing in magento in display 404 page error. can You Tell me What's Issue?

Comment: paste your mention file code too..

Comment: check your module is listed in `system  > configuration > advanced`

Comment: Did you clean the cache?

Comment: i have already clean the cache and also showing in system > configuration > advanced but is not working!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have done,a simple mistake

**`<actve>true</actve>`**

should be

***`<active>true</active>`***'

The tag: **actve** should be *active*

**Edit:** *`If you use linux system,you should check File & folder Name space does  not contain space`*

Comment: Thanks but still is not working

Comment: Clear your cache or disable them

Comment: Yes, i have already do this but is not working!

Comment: i have check ur extension at my system.it is working perfectly.Please clear magento cache

Comment: Really Amit Bera i don't know why is not working my end i access this url : domaina.com/project/index.php/mymodule

Comment: please put this extension on other system and check this

Comment: Thanks, you are correct Amit Bera i have check on window machine this module working fine but i am working  on linux ubuntu machine. its not work

Comment: May you have put some Space in File & folder Name.Plaease

Comment: Finally, Thanks you Amit Beta in folder Name have space. Work fine. Thanks Again

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a web server configuration problem you shouldn't have the `index.php` part in the url.

Try to configure the same store and module over a full qualified url name like:

> http://project.domaina.com/mymodule

Remove the "project" and index.php from the path.